Langchain: LCEL, Add more variables to dic
Below is a langchain chain.
full_chain = {
    "topic": classification_chain,
    "input": lambda x: x["input"],
} | RunnableLambda(route)

I want to add one more variable to this dict but is simple fails :(
full_chain = {
    "topic": classification_chain,
    "input": lambda x: x["input"],
    "chat_history": ''
} | RunnableLambda(route)

with error
  File "/home/garg10may/coding/pipa/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 4871, in coerce_to_runnable
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'str'>


runnable expects dict type data. In your code, the value of "chat_history": '' isn't in dict format.
Reference > https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/interface/ > see the definition under The input type and output type varies by component:
